# case...when or Hash#fetch

Tags: ruby, hash-map

I have the following method, which can be written in the following two ways: which one would you prefer, and why?

```
# version with case...when
def choose(value)
  case value
  when value < LOWER_LIMIT
    'a'
  when value > UPPER_LIMIT
    'b'
  else
    'c'
end

# version with Hash#fetch
def choose(value)
  { (value < LOWER_LIMIT) => 'a',
    (value > UPPER_LIMIT) => 'b'
  }.fetch(true, 'c')
end
```

I personally find the first one more linear and readable.

Comment: What task does this code accomplish? Please tell us, and also make that the title of the question via [edit]. Maybe you missed the placeholder on the title element: "_State the task that your code accomplishes. Make your title distinctive._". Also from  [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._".

Answer (score 1):

I would have just gone for an if/else, this really isn't a good use case for a `case` statement and I've never seen anyone use a hash like that except for demonstration purposes:

```
def choose(value)
  if value < LOWER_LIMIT
    'a'
  elsif value <= UPPER_LIMIT
    'c'
  else
    'b'
 end
end
```

or possibly using a ternary

```
def choose(value)
  value < LOWER_LIMIT ? 'a' : value <= UPPER_LIMIT ? 'c' : 'b'
end
```

note that I find it easier to keep my conditions in ascending order.

If this is a common pattern I would consider extending ranges.

```
class Range
  def case(value, less, in, more)
    if value < first
      less
    elsif include?(value)
       in
    else
       more
    end
  end
end

(LOWER_LIMIT..UPPER_LIMIT).case(value, 'a', 'c', 'b')
```